# How can I locate a process' global and stack areas in Win32?

Tags: winapi, process, multithreading, stack, global

How can I locate which areas of memory of a Win32 process contain the global data and the stack data for each thread?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API (that I know of) to do this.  But If you have a DLL in the process, then you will get DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH/DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notifications in [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885202.aspx) when each thread is created.  You can record the thread ID and the address of a stack object for that thread when you get these notifications, because you will get called on the new thread.  So store the thread id and stack address in some table that you create at that time.  Don't try to do a lot of work in DllMain, just record the stack location and return.

You can then use [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902(VS.85).aspx) to get turn the address of a variable on each thread stack into a virtual allocation range,  that should give you the base address of the stack (remember that stacks grow from high addresses to low addresses).   The default allocation size for a stack is 1Mb, but that can be overridden by a linker switch or by the thread creator, but a stack must be contiguous.  So what you get back from `VirtualQuery` will be the full stack *at that point in time*

As for the heap location - there can be multiple locations for the heap, but in general if you want to assume a single contigous heap location then use [HeapAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366597(VS.85).aspx) to get the address of a heap object and then `VirtualQuery` to determine the range of pages for that section of the heap.

Alternatively You can use `VirtualQuery` on the hModule for the EXE and for each DLL. and then you can assume that anything that is read-write and isn't a stack or a module is part of the heap.  Note that this will be true in most processes, but may not be true in some because an application can call `VirtualAlloc` or `CreateFileMapping` directly, resulting in valid data pointers that are not from either stack or heap. 
Use [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631(VS.85).aspx) to get the the list of modules loaded into a process.

VirtualQuery basically takes a random address, and returns the base address of the collection of pages that that address belongs to, as well as the page protections.  So it's good for going from a specific pointer which 'type' of allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Take the address of variables allocated in the memory regions you are interested. What you do with the addresses when you have them is another question entirely.

You can also `objdump -h` (I think it's -h, might be -x) to list the section addresses, including data sections.

Answer (score 1):

**Global Data**

By "Global" I'm going to assume you mean all the data that is not dynamically allocated using new, malloc, HeapAlloc, VirtualAlloc etc - the data that you may declare in your source code that is outside of functions and outside of class definitions.

You can locate these by loading each DLL as a PE File in a PE file reader and determining the locations of the .data and .bss sections (these may have different names for different compilers). You need to do this for each DLL. That gives you the general locations for this data for each DLL. Then, if you have debugging information, or failing that, a MAP file, you can map the DLL addresses against the debug info/mapfile info to get names and exact locations for each variable.

You may find the [PE Format DLL](http://www.objectmedia.ltd.uk/freeSoftware/peFileDLL.html) helps you perform this task much easier than writing the code to query the PE file yourself.

**Thread Stacks**

Enumerate the threads in the application using ToolHelp32 (or PSAPI library if on Windows NT 4). For each thread, get the thread context and read the ESP register (RSP for x64). Now do a VirtualQuery on the address in the ESP/RSP register read from each context. The 1MB (default value) region around that address (start at mbi.AllocationBase and work upwards 1MB) is the stack location. Note that the stack size may not be 1MB, you can query this from the PE header of the DLL/EXE that started the thread if you wish.

*EDIT*, Fix typo where I swapped some register names, thanks @interjay

Comment: Did you mean ESP instead of EIP?

Comment: @interjay. Whoops! Yes I did. ESP/RSP rather than EIP/RIP. Edited the article to fixup. Thank you for the save.