# How to read a process' memory using code compiled with g++?

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I want to read the process memory of `notepad.exe` and find the string `Hello World!` inside it (it's typed inside a Notepad window).

I want to use `g++.exe`, not `cl.exe`, because it's too much of a hassle to try to figure out how to set the proper environment variables to be able to use it from the command line instead of from inside Visual Studio.  There are other reasons as well, but the thing is I need to use `g++.exe`.

Trying to compile the following code gives the following errors (I know the code, even if run, would do nothing as-is.  But this is a first step):

> `wstring` was not declared in this scope
>
> `szModName` was not declared in this scope
>
> expected `;` before `wstrModContain`
>
> `wstrModContain` was not declared in this scope
>
> `string` has not been declared

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

HMODULE GetModule();

int main() {
    return 0;
}

HMODULE GetModule() {
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "Untitled - Notepad");
    DWORD pID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pID);
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pID);
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    unsigned int i;
    if (EnumProcessModules(pHandle, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded)) {
        for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
            wstring szModName[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(pHandle, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR))) {
                TCHAR* wstrModName = szModName;
                wstring wstrModContain = "notepad.exe";
                if (wstrModName.find(wstrModContain) != string::npos) {
                    CloseHandle(pHandle);
                    return hMods[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, some of the errors are just so basic that I'd also suggest you pick up a book on C++.

Comment: If you are using `windows.h` then I would indeed use visual studio, not GCC as the linux toolchain obviously does not support the windows api. Instead of directly calling cl.exe have you tried actually making a visual studio solution and project to compile your exe?

Comment: You might want to look at the source code of [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/), which is an open source debugger for Windows.  It reads process memory.

Comment: You need to learn C++ before you attempt this stuff to be honest.. However, you should `#include <string>` and change `string::npos` to `std::string::npos` and `wstring` to `std::wstring` to fix your errors.. I'd suggest reading your errors and going through a C++ tutorial.

Comment: @Brandon Including `<string>` and `using namespace std;` is the first thing I tried but doesn't solve anything.  It just changes the undefined `wstring` and `string` errors to `cannot convert` errors.

Comment: A good note to keep in mind is that I believe you should compile your program into the same bit as your target process. (`64bit or 32bit`). I have been working on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777539/c-read-all-memory-from-process-within-modulesize if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you that is very interesting and seems quite relevant to what I'm trying to do.  It will most certainly be helpful in my adventure.

Comment: I hope it is helpful! If you manage to find a correct top address feel free to fork my project and suggest improvements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better answer than my last, since the previous only searched the executable image which only contains what's in the `.exe` file and not it's dynamic memory.

Compile with: `g++ filename.cpp -lpsapi`

The order of the `#include`s is important; `<Windows.h>` must come before `<psapi.h>`.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    DWORD pID;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad"); // the window title

    if (!hwnd)
        std::cout << "FindWindowA Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    if (!GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pID))
        std::cout << "GetWindowThreadProcessId Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    if (!pHandle)
        std::cout << "OpenProcess Error:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for (p = NULL; VirtualQueryEx(pHandle, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info); p += info.RegionSize) {
        std::vector<char> buffer;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) {
            SIZE_T bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
                char value = buffer.at(i);
                std::cout << value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Amusingly my last answer was deleted for calling comments "imbecilic".  Comments which were unhelpful, wrong, patronizing, did not answer the question, yet which were not themselves deleted.

Comment: If you are still interested in working on this you could go to my [github](https://github.com/darclander) and add my discord so we could work together.